# Python library for running variation of an analysis

Tags: library, python, data-analysis

I do a fair bit of data analysis using Python. I find that I often end up repeating the same analysis for different input variables (e.g., looking at GDP and then seeing if the answer changes under GPI) or maybe using a different aggregation technique (e.g., mean vs median).

I was thinking about putting together a python framework to help apply various variations to an analysis but was wondering if there is an existing python library accomplishes this.

Comment: Try googling “monte carlo simulation python”. Lots of hits.

Answer (score 0):

As in other programming languages, one usually accomplishes such a thing in Python by writing a loop or function. For example, if you have an analysis that involves taking the mean of something with `numpy.mean`, you can replace `np.mean` with `f` and wrap the analysis code in a new function that has `f` as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The general term for what you are looking for is Monte Carlo simulations. Although I don't have any personal experience with it, there is a [Monte Carlo feature in the Pandas library](https://pypi.org/project/pandas-montecarlo/). In addition, I found [pyhmc](https://pythonhosted.org/pyhmc/), [pyMC](https://pypi.org/project/pymc/) and [pyMC3](https://pypi.org/project/pymc3/) (which looks like the most up to date).